# How to calculate average value within a polygon(in Qgis with Python)?

Tags: qgis, python, point

Now I have a point and polygon shapefile

and I want to calculate the points' average value within each polygons

How to do it with python?

I tried to find out but google gives me a lot of raster within polygon...

I just want to do it with shapefile

Comment: *Very* closely related is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53678/total-of-attribute-field-of-point-layer-per-polygon-layer.  Perhaps this answers your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment it's very like my problem but it's not really I want ,I want to make it through Python but it's use a plugin within Qgis

Comment: Well, then, please tell us how it's different!

Comment: and I don't have point per polygon in my shapefile I need to calculate it in the begging

Comment: I don't follow: exactly *what* do you need to calculate before you can get this question answered? The question I referenced looks more and more like an exact duplicate of this question; the only thing you need to change is the name of the field you are averaging or summing.

Comment: the most different between my question and that post is I need a python way to do it but he just use a plugin to do it

Comment: Why does it have to be done with just Python? Why can't you use a plugin?

Comment: I have lots of point and polygon shapefile to do with it , it's need too much time to do it with plugin....