# Adding attribute data together within multiple polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, attribute-table, count

In QGIS I have two vector layers, the first is a set of polygons and the second is a series of points.  Each point has a numerical attribute associated with it and is located within one of the polygons.  What I'd like to do is to run a points in a polygon function to collect how many points fall within each polygon but in addition, I would like to sum each of the numerical attributes found in each point so that the end result is a total of the numerical attributes for each polygon.

For example: Say I want to generate a map with the total population of each city in the greater Los Angeles region (County). I have point data representing the centroid of each census block group. I then table join the centroid and the population data associated with each block group.  My attribute table for the centroids then has a column listing the population.  I would like to add the population of each centroid together with the population of other centroids that fall into each city's polygon. I've tried the instructions given in [Total of attribute field of point layer per polygon layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53678/total-of-attribute-field-of-point-layer-per-polygon-layer) but I am still am not getting the results that I need.

Comment: @PolyGeo, thank you for the prompt response: I'm using QGIS and my input rows consist of population counts (integers) and my desired output row would combine the population count from each of the points together to give me a total population for a specific polygon.

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question in response for requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would help you to have to sift through comments for critical information.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the precise steps that *you* performed when trying to follow the instructions in the duplicate question, please? It is by knowing precisely what you have tried and where your observed results deviate from what you were expecting that will make this question answerable.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up with you guys.  I ended up doing a table join and  exporting my new attribute table and running a SumIf function in Excel. I was able to get the information that I needed using Excel and created a new .csv with the new data. I then performed another table join and was able to get the appropriate results. Thank you for taking the time.